# enterprise architect scripting in java: how to change the way of a connector?

Tags: java, uml, enterprise-architect, activity-diagram

I try to change the way of a connector which connects two elements in an activity diagram. I use the Java API (eaapi.jar) from sparx.
My function to connect two elements:

```
public void connectTwoElements(Element source, Element target) {
    Connector con = source.GetConnectors().AddNew("","ControlFlow");
    con.SetSupplierID(target.GetElementID());
    con.Update();
    source.GetConnectors().Refresh();
}
```

My goal is to change the way of connector like in the below right scenario. The way of the connector to the target element should have an edge point to create a 90° angle.
[image]

I didn't found any attribute of the class Connector to implement that. I expect that I can use a function like:
    myConnector.addBetweenPoint(int x, int y);

Maybe anyone can help me:)

Regards,
Phil

**EDIT:**

After Nizam Mohamed and Uffe helps me below, I modified my method:

```
 public void connectTwoElements(Element source, Element target, String connectorLabel) {
    Connector con = source.GetConnectors().AddNew(connectorLabel,"ControlFlow");        
    con.SetSupplierID(target.GetElementID());
    con.Update();        
    source.GetConnectors().Refresh();
    diagram.GetDiagramLinks().Refresh();

    //change style of diagram link
    Collection<DiagramLink> diagramLinks = diagram.GetDiagramLinks();
    for(DiagramLink dl : diagramLinks){
        if(dl.GetConnectorID()==con.GetConnectorID()){
            dl.SetStyle("Mode=3;TREE=LV;");
            dl.Update();
            diagram.GetDiagramLinks().Refresh();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It is important to Refresh() the Collection DiagramLinks of the Diagram after add a new Connector because otherwise the DiagramLink isn't available in the Collection DiagramLinks to change the style. Of course you must Refresh() it again after changing the style.

Comment: I suggest you to dig a little for `SetRouteStyle` and `SetStyleEx` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the linestyle to Orthogonal - Square or Lateral - Vertical to achieve this.
To do this, you need to get the DiagramLink and set its style.

Below are some combinations

(for Orthogonal Square) Mode=3;TREE=OS;

(for Lateral Vertical) Mode=3;TREE=LV;

Comment: Hello Nizam Mohamed, thank you very much for your answer. It work's:)

Answer (score 1):

Like elements, whose visual representation in one specific diagram is represented by a `DiagramObject`, a `DiagramLink` controls the display of one connector in one diagram. So if you want to change the connector's appearance in one diagram without affecting any others, you need to retrieve the relevant `DiagramLink` from `Diagram.DiagramLinks` and make your changes to that.

No method along your suggested lines exists, so the simplest way forward is probably to draw some connectors that look the way you want them and then check the database (t_connector and t_diagramlinks) to see how that geometry is represented.

Comment: Hey Uffe, thank you very much again:-) You are my EA-Scripting hero!